# Is it possible to remove the corners to get the rounded and smooth edges using smooth tool?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image: smooth edges or an icon]

Using Pen Tool, I tried to draw the hair of the user account icon. The Smooth Tool helped its best, but, sill there is need for smooth curves in the hair of the icon. Any tips which might improve my icon design skills? Thank you in advance.

SVG source file: https://svgshare.com/i/L6S.svg

Comment: Yes, but this ist really something you should be using for this illustration.

Comment: [Anchor point tool](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/editing-paths.html#convert_an_anchor_point_precisely_using_the_convert_anchor_point_tool)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you mean by rounding the corners. Here are a couple of possibilities.

1. Use Illustrator CC's corner widgets to round the corners

or

2. Apply a Corner "Round Join" in the Stroke panel.

[image]

or

3. Convert corner anchors to smooth anchors using the Anchor Point tool.

[image]

Comment: once again, thanks a lot @Billy_Kerr.